# Convert String Characters to Text

Tags: excel, vba, string

I'm trying to convert a large amount of data into a written description of the text. Ex. Convert YYYY####### to "4 digit year, 7 numeric digits" and YYMMDD-#### to "2 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit day, hyphen, 4 numeric digits"

The constant characters are Y, M, D, #, - and X (X is for non-defined alpha characters). There are some defined alpha characters (Y, M, D and X are never used for anything other than Year, Month, Day and Alpha respectively) that are used, ie (RP-YYYY#####) where I want to try to capture those (anything other than the constant characters) and state them as they are. So the written text for RP-YYYY##### would be "RP, hypen, 4 digit year, 5 numeric digits"

I'm able to get a count of each character using the Len and Replace methods, however I'm struggling to figure out how to produce the written text in the correct order, or to capture non constant characters like RP and state them as is.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub getcharacters()
Dim casenumber As String

casenumber = Range("A1")
InitialCount = Len(casenumber)
YearDigits = Len(casenumber) - Len(Replace(casenumber, "Y", ""))
MonthDigits = Len(casenumber) - Len(Replace(casenumber, "MM", ""))
DayDigits = Len(casenumber) - Len(Replace(casenumber, "DD", ""))
NumberDigits = Len(casenumber) - Len(Replace(casenumber, "#", ""))
AlphaDigits = Len(casenumber) - Len(Replace(casenumber, "X", ""))
HyphenDigits = Len(casenumber) - Len(Replace(casenumber, "-", ""))
FinalCount = InitialCount - YearDigits - MonthDigits - DayDigits - Digits - AlphaDigits

If YearDigits = "0" Then WrittenYear = ""
If YearDigits = "2" Then WrittenYear = "Two digit year"
If YearDigits = "4" Then WrittenYear = "Four digit year"
If MonthDigits = "0" Then WrittenMonth = "" Else WrittenMonth = "Two digit month"
If DayDigits = "0" Then WrittenDay = "" Else WrittenDay = "Two digit day"
If NumberDigits = "0" Then WrittenDigits = "" Else WrittenDigits = NumberDigits & " digits"
If AlphaDigits = "0" Then WrittenAlpha = "" Else WrittenAlpha = AlphaDigits & " alpha characters"
WrittenCaseNumber = WrittenYear & WrittenMonth & WrittenDay & WrittenDigits & WrittenAlpha
End Sub
```

Comment: So, you have two problems?   Check me on this:
1) You must find the order in which the first letter Y, M, or D appear and sort the three.
2) You must count the number of Ys, Ms, and Ds that follow the first
3) You must print out words like 'One', "Two" or for year, "Four" for that count
4) Count pound-signs, reported as "numeric digits"  

- Are the pound signs always going to be last?
- Do you want to describe the presence of a hyphen in words if there is one?
- Do you want error-checking for bad combinations?   Like characters not on the list above?   Or 3 Y characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Regex for the matching and replacing part along with some helper functions to convert digits to words, etc. I admit it's a bit ugly but it does the trick.

First, add the following two references to your project:

- Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Second, add the following code to a Module:

```
Option Explicit

Private DictAlphaCharacters As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub InitializeDictAlphaCharacters()
    Set DictAlphaCharacters = New Scripting.Dictionary
    DictAlphaCharacters.Add "Y", "digit year"
    DictAlphaCharacters.Add "M", "digit month"
    DictAlphaCharacters.Add "D", "digit day"
    DictAlphaCharacters.Add "#", "numeric digits"
End Sub

Public Function DescribeThis(s As String) As String
    If DictAlphaCharacters Is Nothing Then InitializeDictAlphaCharacters

    Dim tmpStr As String: tmpStr = s

    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    regEx.Global = True
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim m As Match

    Dim k As Variant        ' Dictionary key.
    Dim alpha As String     ' The corresponding sentence for an alpha char.
    Dim l As Integer        ' Length of the matched string (consecutive alpha chars).
    Dim w As String         ' The corresponding word of a digit.

    For Each k In DictAlphaCharacters.Keys
        alpha = DictAlphaCharacters.Item(k)
        regEx.Pattern = k & "{1,9}"
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(tmpStr)
        For Each m In matches
            l = m.Length
            w = DigitToWord(l)
            ' Pattern ex. = "([^Y])?,?Y{2}(?!Y)"
            regEx.Pattern = "([^" & k & "])?,?" & k & "{" & l & "}(?!" & k & ")"
            '         Replacement example: "$1,Two digit year,"
            tmpStr = regEx.Replace(tmpStr, "$1," & w & " " & alpha & ",")
        Next
    Next

    regEx.Pattern = ",?-,?"
    tmpStr = regEx.Replace(tmpStr, ",hyphen,")

    regEx.Pattern = "^,+|,+$"
    DescribeThis = regEx.Replace(tmpStr, "")
End Function

Public Function DigitToWord(d As Integer) As String
    Select Case d
        Case 1: DigitToWord = "One"
        Case 2: DigitToWord = "Two"
        Case 3: DigitToWord = "Three"
        Case 4: DigitToWord = "Four"
        Case 5: DigitToWord = "Five"
        Case 6: DigitToWord = "Six"
        Case 7: DigitToWord = "Seven"
        Case 8: DigitToWord = "Eight"
        Case 9: DigitToWord = "Nine"
    End Select
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print DescribeThis("YYYY#######")
    Debug.Print DescribeThis("YYMMDD-####")
    Debug.Print DescribeThis("RP-YYYY#####")
    Debug.Print DescribeThis("YYYMMM-YYMM")
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
Four digit year,Seven numeric digits
Two digit year,Two digit month,Two digit day,hyphen,Four numeric digits
RP,hyphen,Four digit year,Five numeric digits
Three digit year,Three digit month,hyphen,Two digit year,Two digit month
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I didn't post everything that I've tried but I've been working on this for days! This worked perfectly! I cannot thank you enough!!!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to accomplish what you want.

As written it assumes that all of the "like" characters in the set of [YMD#] are contiguous.  If groups of `Y`'s, for example, could repeat in different parts of the string, we just need to change the `charCnt` function.

```
Option Explicit
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Function convStr(S As String) As String
    Dim myDict As Dictionary
    Dim sRes() As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim CH As String

Set myDict = New Dictionary
    myDict.CompareMode = TextCompare

    myDict.Add "Y", "digit year"
    myDict.Add "M", "digit month"
    myDict.Add "D", "digit day"
    myDict.Add "#", "numeric digits"
    myDict.Add "-", "hyphen"

ReDim sRes(0)
For I = 1 To Len(S)
    CH = Mid(S, I, 1)
    If myDict.Exists(CH) Then
        sRes(UBound(sRes)) = IIf(CH <> "-", charCnt(S, CH) & " ", "") & myDict(CH)
        I = I + charCnt(S, CH)
    Else
        Do While Not myDict.Exists(CH)
            sRes(UBound(sRes)) = sRes(UBound(sRes)) & CH
            I = I + 1
            CH = Mid(S, I, 1)
        Loop
    End If

I = I - 1
ReDim Preserve sRes(UBound(sRes) + 1)
Next I

ReDim Preserve sRes(UBound(sRes) - 1)

convStr = Join(sRes, ", ")

End Function

Function charCnt(S As String, CH As String) As Long
    Dim startChar As Long
startChar = InStr(S, CH)

If startChar > 0 Then
    charCnt = Len(S) - Len(Replace(S, CH, ""))
Else
    charCnt = 0
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: The only characters that in theory would not be contiguous would be the # characters, Sometimes they show up in chunks before or after dates and hyphens. I'm relatively new to vba and wasn't able to get your code to work, though it obviously did for you. I'm unsure where to designate my range in the code.

Comment: @JVA It's a function. It takes a single cell as the argument.